# objective-c: drawRect - path draws incomplete

Tags: objective-c, drawrect, cgpath

I'm trying to draw a hexagon and have been following a couple of tutorials online. But I must be doing something wrong as my results are always an incomplete path. Initially I thought it was because I was making the view frame too small but even when I bump the w/h to 800 I still get the same results. Here's my code:

FEG_Map is a UIView which is set in the viewcontroller and will hold the hex grid.

```
@implementation FEG_Map

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) addHex {

    float rowX = 400.0;
    float rowY = 10.0;

        FEG_Hex* thisHex = [[FEG_Hex alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rowX, rowY, 800.0, 800.0)];
        thisHex.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:thisHex];

}
```

in FEG_Hex I over ride drawRect and add:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {


    //create mutable path
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    //go to start point
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, _origin.x, _origin.y);

    //move along hex path
    CGPoint newloc = CGPointMake(_origin.x - 20, _origin.y + 42);
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x, newloc.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x + 16,newloc.y + 38);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x + 49, newloc.y + 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x + 23,  newloc.y - 39);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x - 25,newloc.y - 40);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x -43, newloc.y + 0);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    //add a context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //add path to context
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);

    //stroke path
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    //set the stroke color
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);




}
```

and my results are:

[image]

Comment: Fill the `rect` so you know where you're drawing. Log the points as you create them (or log the path that is created).

Comment: What is `_origin` set to (0,0 perhaps)?  Use a different backgroundColor for the view so you can see the border.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
CGPoint newloc = CGPointMake(_origin.x - 20, _origin.y + 42);
```

to

```
CGPoint newloc = CGPointMake(_origin.x + 42, _origin.y + 20);
```

and you will see your hexagon. But it not correct.

For obtain more correct hexagon use this code:

```
CGPoint newloc = CGPointMake(_origin.x + 46, _origin.y + 20);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x + 23, newloc.y + 40);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x + 46, newloc.y + 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x + 23, newloc.y - 40);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x - 23, newloc.y - 40);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x - 46, newloc.y + 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newloc.x - 23, newloc.y + 40);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```